# Android DatePicker help, knowing which EditText called

Tags: android, datepicker

I'm following this tutorial: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-datepicker.html .

I have two EditText, and which one calls showDialog(0) that is the DatePickerDialog. How can I know which EditText called the showDialog? Because the updateDisplay (method in tutorial) doesn't show how to do this!

Comment: Can you some more clear with your question?

Comment: I don't really get your problem. If you fire an onClick event from one of your EditText, you will mostly have a listener set to each of them or your activity will implement an onClickListener where the EditTexts get distinguished

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your OnClick method, you can get which view was clicked

```
view.getId()
```

Then, compare it to the id of your editTexts (the ids that you set on the xml file) and you will know which one was called